# How to Create Select Box in Registration Form in Joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I am using Joomla 1.6 and I have created a text field in registration form (which is driven by `components\com_users\models\forms\registration.xml`) like this:

```
<field name="City" type="text"
            description="COM_USERS_DESIRED_CITY"
            filter="string"
            label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_CITY_LABEL"
            message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_CITY_MESSAGE"
            required="true"
            size="30"
        />
```

Now I want to convert this text field (city) to select box, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to change the `type` attribute from "text" to "list" and then include the options you want available. For example:

```
<field name="City" type="list"
        description="COM_USERS_DESIRED_CITY"
        filter="string"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_CITY_LABEL"
        message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_CITY_MESSAGE"
        required="true"
        size="30">
    <option value="ny">New York</option>
    <option value="chicago">Chicago</option>
    <option value="la">Los Angeles</option>
</field>
```